# Direct connect to PostgreSQL without ArcSDE?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, postgis, arcgis-10.0, postgresql

I have postgreSQL installed on my machine.My machine already has ArcGIS 10. No Sde installed. Can we create geodatabase in PostgreSQL with out installing ArcSDE?

---

Jay Cummins is right. I am intended to use create esri geodatabase. Can we do this with direct connect by simply installing postgreSQL on same/remote machine? Can we connect to Postgres with ArcCatalog and create featureclasses. Can we load raster in it? I have seen in many articles mentioning post-installer to setup the ArcSDE objects in the database even for direct connect. Should we need ArcSDE?

Comment: If we are assuming that the `geodatabase` is an Esri geodatabase, then I don't think the question is a duplicate of the above-mentioned question.  Although I think there are 2 separate questions here.  Can you direct connect? Can you create the `Esri` geodatabase in PostgreSQL without ArcSDE.

Comment: @JayCummins - Point taken.  Hopefully the OP can provide some insight on whether they want to create an `ESRI` geodatabase in PostgreSQL, or if the objective is to simply store spatial data in a PostGIS/PostgreSQL database and access it through ArcGIS.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you only want to read the database and don't mind losing the "features" of a GeoDatabase (I'm not actually sure what the benefits are myself), then ArcGIS 10 allows you to use something called Query Layers:
http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/04/14/query-layers-arcgis-10/

Alternately you can use "Direct Connect", which was in 9.x - http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Properties_of_a_direct_connection_to_an_ArcSDE_geodatabase
In relation to PostGreSQL:

> If you make a direct connection from an ArcGIS client, such as ArcGIS Desktop, no additional installation is needed on the client machine. If, however, you want to connect from a third-party client, each client machine from which you make a direct connection to the database must have the appropriate connectivity driver (such as psqlODBC or JDBC) installed and configured. Consult the documentation for your third-party software for information on the appropriate driver.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the updated information in your question, I think it is pretty clear that you need to have a license of [ArcGIS for Server](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgisserver/index.html).  This software now has ArcSDE integrated into it.

Based on this article:  [Storage in a Relational Database Management System](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/geodatabase/storage-in-an-rdbms.html) - I think it is clear that to create an ESRI Geodatabase in PostgreSQL, which is an RDBMS, you need the ArcSDE technology.

This document shows the breakdown of the [Multi-User Geodatabase](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/geodatabase/multi-user-geodatabase.html) types offered by ESRI.

The only other types of ESRI Geodatabases, are the [Single User Geodatabases](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/geodatabase/single-user-geodatabase.html).  There are two types, the Personal Geodatabase and the File Geodatabase.  These can both be created using a standard ArcGIS installation, or you can use the [OGR libraries](http://gdal.org/ogr/) to create them outside of the ESRI software products, using the [File Geodatabase API](http://resources.arcgis.com/content/geodatabases/10.0/file-gdb-api).

Update for clarity
If you are using [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org), or another supported RDBMS as your spatial data repository, there are two ways you may access data.

- If you wish to see **ESRI** object types like  `Feature Classes`; `Feature Datasets`; `Geometric Networks`, `Relationship Classes`, `Raster Catalog`, etc; or perform **ESRI-based** operations like `geodatabase versioning`, `replication` and `synchronization`, then you must go through this installation process:  [ArcSDE 10 for PostgreSQL Installation Guide](http://help.arcgis.com/en/geodatabase/10.0/install_guides/arcsde_for_postgresql_installation_and_upgrade_guide/index.html#/Introduction/00q300000037000000/)  This process requires the ArcGIS Server license that you have.
- If you solely want to store geographic data in the RDBMS using the [Open Geospatial Consortium's](http://www.opengeospatial.org) [Implementation Specification for Geographic Information, Simple Features Access for SQL](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/sfs), which is an open standard, and access it through ArcGIS, then you need to do the following:

  1. Install [PostGIS](http://www.postgis.org) for PostgreSQL - This provides the geographic object support for the RDBMS.
  2. In ArcGIS, you will use the [Make Query Table](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000006r000000) command to create a spatial layer or data table using an SQL query from the PostGIS spatial database.

  This does not require a license of ArcGIS Server, but again, your data will not be stored in the ESRI object types listed above.

Comment: Thanks Get Spatial. I do have ArcGIS Server license. By saying ArcSDE integrated, are you saying that there is no seperate installation that runs when I install the ArcGIS Software. In other words, I do not have to follow an order while installing Postgres and ArcGIS (since there is not additional tier that sits on top of Postgres). Or Do I still need to run a seperate installation for PostgreSQL.